# Why "this" keyword returns Window?

Tags: javascript

why in this case "this" is a Window?
I thought it would be Dog object, because it is on the left side of the dot.

```
 const Dog = {
        name: 'Spike',
        showThisDog: () => {
          console.log(this)
        }
    }

Dog.showThisDog()
```

I think I don't get how this keyword works. Can anyone explain it with this example?
Thank U.

Comment: A fat arrow function doesn't create a function scope so the only scope here is the window. What is your expectation? There is no object scope in JavaScript.

Comment: [Arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions): _"Does not have its own bindings to `this` or `super`, **and should not be used as methods.**"_ Why? -> [Arrow functions used as methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#arrow_functions_used_as_methods)

Answer (score 0):

Your Dog object has no reference to `this` other than the Window. If you want to reference an internal property, try `this.name`.

In the global execution context (outside of any function), `this` refers to the global object.

> Inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is called.
> [...] because the value of `this` is not set by the call, `this` will default to the global object, which is window in a browser.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#function_context